# A MySQL EXPLAIN number of rows discrepancy

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, performance-tuning

MySQL 5.5.49-log

More questions on the query in [Why does it use temporary? (MySQL)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175377/5061) (the query is the same but the question is different):

I have the following table (filled with many rows):

```
CREATE TABLE `SectorGraphs2` (
  `Kind` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '1 - продюсер, 2 - жанр, 3 - регион',
  `Criterion` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Period` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PeriodStart` date NOT NULL,
  `SectorID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Value` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `SectorGraphs2`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Producer2` (`Kind`,`Criterion`,`Period`,`PeriodStart`,`SectorID`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `SectorID` (`SectorID`);
```

then I run:

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT SectorID, SUM(Value)
    FROM SectorGraphs2
    WHERE Kind = 1 AND Criterion = 7
      AND Period = 1
      AND PeriodStart >= ? AND PeriodStart < ? + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    GROUP BY SectorID
```

and it produces:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SectorGraphs2 | range | Producer2     | Producer2 | 6       | NULL | 1    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

See a nicely formatted explanation [here](https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/?client=phpMyAdmin&raw_explain=%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B%0A%7C%20id%20%7C%20select_type%20%7C%20table%20%7C%20type%20%7C%20possible_keys%20%7C%20key%20%7C%20key_len%20%7C%20ref%20%7C%20rows%20%7C%20Extra%20%7C%0A%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B%0A%7C%201%20%7C%20SIMPLE%20%7C%20SectorGraphs2%20%7C%20range%20%7C%20Producer2%20%7C%20Producer2%20%7C%206%20%7C%20NULL%20%7C%201%20%7C%20Using%20where%3B%20Using%20temporary%3B%20Using%20filesort%20%7C%0A%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B---%2B%0A).

My question: Why it is used a temporary table and filesort but it reports only 1 row examined? It seems that because of using a temporary table, it should process more than one row. How can I determine the real number of rows processed? How to solve this discrepancy about number of processed rows?

Note that the task I was assigned to do now is to eliminate heavy (involving too many rows) queries. And now I do not know how to do this.

Comment: As Rick has explain there,"an index cannot handle both a range (PeriodStart...) and a GROUP BY" .If this is your real table and real query then I too am astonished becasue your table only contain int and date so it should be super fast.Hope you are using variable in your query as sugested below.Is estimated and actual number of rows same in plan ?Do you get same plan for other parameter also ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `AND PeriodStart >= ? AND PeriodStart < ? + INTERVAL 1 WEEK` clause with precalculated version:

```
SET @PeriodEnd = ? + INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
SELECT SectorID, SUM(Value)
    FROM SectorGraphs2
    WHERE Kind = 1 AND Criterion = 7
      AND Period = 1
      AND PeriodStart BETWEEN ? AND @PeriodEnd
    GROUP BY SectorID;
```

Explicitly point the index you want to use:

```
SET @PeriodEnd = ? + INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
SELECT SectorID, SUM(Value)
    FROM SectorGraphs2 USE INDEX (`Producer2`)
    WHERE Kind = 1 AND Criterion = 7
      AND Period = 1
      AND PeriodStart BETWEEN ? AND @PeriodEnd
    GROUP BY SectorID;
```

Reorder fields in the index definition placing more selective fields first. To determine selectivity run the next query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT Criterion )
  FROM SectorGraphs2;
```

Then replace `Criterion` with `Kind`, `PeriodStart`, `SectorID` etc.

The higher count means better selectivity and you have to arrange fields in the index from the best selectivity to worst.